# Is there a way to run a setup method for all my JUnit test case while using maven failsafe?

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-3

I have few integration tests classes that all depend on starting a test web server.
 Is there a way to start the webserver once before each test class than destroying and starting the webserver with each test class using maven failsafe and JUnit without using JUnit suites?

Comment: Are you looking for the pre-integration and post-integration phases?

Comment: Yea but not for just one test, for all the IT tests in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have integration tests and already using maven-failsafe-plugin you can bind the start of a webserver to the `pre-integration-test` phase and stop it in  `post-integration` phase while the integration tests will run in the `integration-test` phase.

Comment: These have to be bind to a maven plugin, is there a way to bind it to a custom webserver ?

Comment: You could use https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html or use a jetty webserver where exist a https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html